# Creating a map of attribute to object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following:

```
data class Thing(val name: String, val attributes: List<String>)
```

Given a `List<Thing>` I'd like to create a map of attribute `String` to `List<Thing>`. Broadly, things would be grouped by their respective attribute.

First thing that comes to mind is `flatMap` with a combination of `associateBy`, but how they might fit together isn't exactly clear.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What do you have as input? `List<Thing>`? Please add the desired signature of method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect all available attributes and then use `associate` to create `Pair`s of the single attributes and the `Thing`s that have the corresponding attribute. It will result in a map as specified.

```
val things = listOf(
    Thing("first", listOf("a1", "a3")),
    Thing("second", listOf("a2", "a3", "a4"))
)
val result = things
    .flatMap { it.attributes }
    .associate { att ->
        att to things.filter { it.attributes.contains(att) }
    }
```

The Result will look as follows:

```
a1=[Thing(name=first, attributes=[a1, a3])], 
a3=[Thing(name=first, attributes=[a1, a3]), Thing(name=second, attributes=[a2, a3, a4])], 
a2=[Thing(name=second, attributes=[a2, a3, a4])], 
a4=[Thing(name=second, attributes=[a2, a3, a4])]
```

Comment: Thank you. Granted both solutions proposed look to work, this looks the cleanest.

Appreciate the assist!

Answer (score 1):

Given a list of `Thing`:

```
val elements = listOf(
    Thing("First", listOf("A", "B")),
    Thing("Second", listOf("A", "B")),
    Thing("Third", listOf("A"))
)
```

You can use [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html):

```
fun List<Thing>.groupByAttributeAtIndex(attributeIndex: Int): Map<String?, List<Thing>> {
  return groupBy { it.attributes.getOrNull(attributeIndex) }
}
```

To group by attribute at index e.g. `val grouped = elements.groupByAttributeAtIndex(1)` would result in following `Map`:

```
{
    B=[Thing(name=First, attributes=[A, B]), Thing(name=Second, attributes=[A, B])], 
    null=[Thing(name=Third, attributes=[A])]
}
```